# How to solve the error in the below email content in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, email

I am using C# MVC Architecture.

I am going to retrieve the questions from the database and display in the email content as a list of questions.

Below is the method of the email template.

```
 public bool SendJobAcceptanceToRecruiter(string recruiterName, string recruiterEmail, string jobTitle,string joblink, string mailBody, string organization, List<JobQuestion> ques)
    {
        string subject = "Job Advert Accepted - " + jobTitle + "-" + organization;
        var generaltemplate = GetEmailTemplate("GENERAL EMAIL TEMPLATE");
        var template = "<br/>Hello " + organization + "<br/>" +
        "<br/>Your Job Advert has now been accepted.<br/>" +
        "<br/>View Job Posted: " + joblink + "<br/>" +
         "<br/>Questions Posted: " + ques + "<br/>" +
        "<br/>Please contact us if you need more information.<br/>";
        var body = generaltemplate.Replace("@Content", template);
        body = body.Replace("@Orgname", organization);        
        body = body.Replace("@JobLink", joblink) + GetEmailFooter();
        var result = _emailProvider.SendEmail(recruiterEmail, subject, body, true);     
        return result;
    }
```

Here for the List of questions, I get the questions as below.

[image]

[image]

I want to display the 'Question' in the second image as list of questions(In the above case as the count is 7,want to display the 7 questions) with numbering starting from 1.(Number of questions may differ according to the advert.) as a list in the email content.

Every other details(jobTitle,JobLink,RecruiterEmail etc..) are displayed in the email.
Only the 'ques' under Questions Posted: in the email content are displayed as

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I want the content to be displayed as,

1.Question 1

2.Question 3

3.Question 3
...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "unfold" the list of questions, if you do that, you'll have all the freedom you need.

In stead of:

```
"<br/>Questions Posted: " + ques + "<br/>"
```

use something like this:

```
"<br/>Questions Posted: " + string.Join(", ",Enumerable.Range(0, ques.Count()).Select(n => n.Description).ToArray()) + "<br/>"
```

Or for better readability:

```
var template = "<br/>Hello " + organization + "<br/>" +
"<br/>Your Job Advert has now been accepted.<br/>" +
"<br/>View Job Posted: " + joblink + "<br/>" +
"<br/>Questions Posted: ";

foreach(var question in ques)
    template += $"somthing {question.Description} something"

template += "<br/>Please contact us if you need more information.<br/>";

var body = generaltemplate.Replace("@Content", template);
```

---

Further optimization: use a `StringBuilder`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<br/>Hello " + organization + "<br/>");
sb.AppendLine("<br/>Your Job Advert has now been accepted.<br/>");
sb.AppendLine("<br/>View Job Posted: " + joblink + "<br/>");
sb.AppendLine("<br/>Questions Posted: ");

foreach(var question in ques)
{
    sb.AppendLine($"somthing {question.Description} something");
}

sb.AppendLine("<br/>Please contact us if you need more information.<br/>");

var body = generaltemplate.Replace("@Content", sb.ToString());
```

---

Addition: for numbering you have various options. Here's a simple one to understand:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<br/>Hello " + organization + "<br/>");
sb.AppendLine("<br/>Your Job Advert has now been accepted.<br/>");
sb.AppendLine("<br/>View Job Posted: " + joblink + "<br/>");
sb.AppendLine("<br/>Questions Posted: ");

int number = 0;
foreach(var question in ques)
{
    sb.AppendLine($"QUESTION {++number}");
    sb.AppendLine($"somthing {question.Description} something");
}

sb.AppendLine("<br/>Please contact us if you need more information.<br/>");

var body = generaltemplate.Replace("@Content", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: @rissa: added an option with numbering.